# find div parents parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following structure

```
<div>
    <div id="tabHeader">
    <div id="close"></div>
...

</div>
```

I want to select using jquery first `<div>` to close it on close click (`<div id="close"></div>`)

update

I want to close first div (root) on this example when clicking on div id = close

Comment: Which div you wand to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML to this (give class to first div)

```
<div class="main-tab">
    <div id="tabHeader">
    <div id="close"></div>
...
</div>
```

& jQuery

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.main-tab').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your your html :

```
<div>
    <div id="tabHeader">
    <div id="close"></div>
...
</div>
```

You would use :

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

According to the following ("tabHeader" `</div>` added):

```
<div>
    <div id="tabHeader"></div>
    <div id="close"></div>
...
</div>
```

You would use :

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the parent :

```
$(selector).parent().hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/parent/